# convert fr month to en month in moments.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert date from fr to en and then again to fr using moment.js library, date is something like 10, Avril 2016, but I want to log it out as en 10, April 2016 and then convert it back to 10, Avril 2016, how can I do it moments.js. Below is the code.

Date received: 10, Avril 2016

```
moment.locale('en'); 
if(moment(date, 'D, MMM YYYY', true).isValid()) {
   console.log(moment(date, 'D, MMM YYYY')) // I want to show en date 10, April 2016
   console.log() // I want to convert back again and show fr date 10, Avril 2016
}
```

I have used locale option of moments.js but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

You can change locale locally using [`locale`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) method. This will change only locale for the given instance, while [`moment.locale(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) will change it globally.

When you parse your string to convert it to moment object, you can use moment [constructor specifying locale](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```
moment(String, String, String, Boolean);
```

You can use the following code as example:

```js
var date = '10, Avril 2016';
// Parsing string using locale 'fr'
var mom = moment(date, 'D, MMMM YYYY', 'fr', true);
if(mom.isValid()) {
   // Displaying date in french
   console.log(mom.locale('fr').format('D, MMMM YYYY')); // 10, avril 2016
   // Displaying date in english
   console.log(mom.locale('en').format('D, MMMM YYYY')); // 10, April 2016
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to convert the date to milliseconds, and then u can use date in multylocation:

`var z = moment(date, 'D, MMMM YYYY').valueOf()`

```
moment(z).format("D, MMMM YYYY");
"10, avril 2016"
moment.locale('en'); 
"en"
moment(z).format("D, MMMM YYYY")
"10, April 2016"
moment.locale('fr'); 
"fr"
moment(z).format("D, MMMM YYYY")
"10, avril 2016"
```